# Correlation between regressors and error term

Tags: regression, residuals

I have a question regarding linear regression that has been confusing me for some time. Consider the linear regression model in matrix notation $$Y=X\beta+\epsilon$$

Consider now the OLS estimator that can be derived from the moment condition:$$E[X'\epsilon]=0$$

Now, we can write the vector of estimated error terms as:$$e=Y-X\hat{\beta}$$

In a way, holding $\hat{\beta}$
fixed we have expressed the vector of residuals as a function of the $Xs$.
In a sense, we can write the e's
as a linear function of the $X's$.
However, functions that are linearly related to each other are perfectly correlated. How can that be? The precise moment condition uses the fact that in the population, $E[X'\epsilon]=0$?

Comment: At some point you seem to have forgotten that $\hat\beta$ is a function of $X$.  Consequently, $e$ is not a linear function of $X$ at all.

Comment: Thank you. But if the estimated paramters are a function of X, and if the residuals are a  function of the estimated parameters, then how are the residuals not a function of X?

Comment: Simple question, shouldn't the equation be $Y = X\hat\beta+\varepsilon$ without transposing the model matrix $X$?

Comment: "We can write the e's as a linear function of the $X$s" is not true, as @whuber observes.  "we have expressed the vector of residuals as a function of the $X$s" is true.  Look carefully for the differences between the two statements!

Comment: @Antoni The *model* is $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$.  When it is *fit*, the residuals are *defined* via the relationship $Y = X\hat\beta + e$.  The OLS solution (when $X$ is of full rank) is $e = Y - X(X^\prime X)^{-1}X^{\prime}Y$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. The varepsiolon $\varepsilon$, epsilon $\epsilon$ and simple 'e' $e$ are easy to disrespect, always at at the end of the equation, and even easier to mix up...